# what does 'carrier' generally mean in LTE?

Tags: lte

In LTE they talk about carrier a lot. It's not verizon, at&t and etc but seems to be different things. 
What does 'carrier' mean in LTE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not appear to be a specific programming problem as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrier can mean two things in the LTE world:

- the operator, as Juan mentions
- the radio channel that 'carrys' the data

I think the latter is probably what you are referring to and this is definitely what is meant when the term 'carrier aggregation' is used - this essentially allows LTE combine the data carrying capabilities of multiple 'channels' to increase the overall bandwidth either to or from the device.

Answer (score 3):

In LTE, carrier is the center frequency of the spectrum being used to transmit the LTE signal. More spectrum, higher the speed.

This is called or referred to as EARFCN. Eutra Absolute radio-frequency channel number.

In recent times, you will hear about carrier-aggregation. This is the ability of the mobile device to combine multiple of these defined spectrum for transmission of signal for much higher download speeds.